# How to get the element from the returned collection of .childNodes method

Tags: javascript, dom, object, element

example:

```
function something( )
{
    var elementObjects = document.getElementById( "anElement" );
    var children = elementObjects.childNodes; // assuming element with id = "anElement" has children
}
```

from variable children, how can i get the objects' element object.  Because by default, .childNodes returns objects, not element objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a NodeList is similar to an array, but you use .item() to access members:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myNodeList.length; i++) {
    var el = myNodeList.item(i);
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

childNodes returns an array of objects, inorder to access individual element you have iterate through this array and access the elementobjects.